# How to calculate number of indirect dependencies of a class?

Tags: recursion, graph-traversal, circular-dependency, dependency-analysis

Most of the static code analysis tools which analyse class dependencies generate dependency pairs of classes where each pair represents a direct dependency between two classes. Given those dependency pairs, it is straight forward to calculate number of *direct* dependencies of a particular class. However, if we have to compute number of *indirect* dependencies of a class, I realized that the algorithm is fairly complex. Let me clarify what I mean by indirect dependency:

We have following *direct* dependency class pairs:

Class A depends on Class B

Class B depends on Class C

Class B depends on Class D

In this case, class A depends directly on class B and indirectly on classes C and D.

I would define number of direct dependencies for class A as 1 and number of indirect dependencies for class A as 2.

I would like to compute indirect dependencies for each and every class in the systems that I analyse.

The complexity arises mainly due to cyclic dependencies.

For example, if we were to compute number of indirect dependencies for class A:

Scenario 1:

A -> B

B -> C

C -> D

D -> B

Scenario 2:

A -> B

B -> C

B -> D

C -> E

D -> F

E -> G

F -> G

G -> H

Scenario 3:

A -> B

B -> C

C -> A

Can this be solved by using graph theory? For example, represent all dependency pairs using a directed graph and calculate recursive sum of outdegrees of adjacent nodes. Any other ideas are welcome.

Let me know what is the best way to get it.

Comment: Any graph traversal algorithm will solve your problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal

Comment: @gnat The link you quote says that "algorithm and data structure concepts" are on-topic. That seems to be what the poster is asking about. +1 from me.

Comment: @kiwiron request for software recommendation was deleted out of the question, see [revisions history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/294223/revisions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the direct dependencies is very straightforward. So for your purposes I'd recommend finding the count of *all* dependencies, then if you're interested in indirect only, you can just subtract the number of direct from the total.

The algorithm isn't too tricky, and in pseudocode would look something like:

```
count = 0
visited = [ ]
toVisit = [ startNode ]
while(toVisit not empty)
{
    current = toVisit.Pop
    for(dependency in current.dependencies)
    {
        if(dependency not in visited)
            toVisit.Push(dependency)
    }
    visited.Push(current)
    count++;
}
```

You're just traversing the graph, keeping track of all nodes already visited to make sure you don't revisit them (avoiding issues arising due to circular dependencies).

Comment: Simple and accurate.  I couldn't have written it better myself.